# How do I remove english stop words from a dataframe column using a custom dictionary of stop words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tweets

I'm writing a function that takes in a dataframe(df) of tweets as input. I need to tokenize the tweets and remove the stop words and add this output to a new column. I can't import anything except numpy and pandas.

The stop words are in a dictionary as follows:

```
stop_words_dict = {
'stopwords':[
    'where', 'done', 'if', 'before', 'll', 'very', 'keep', 'something', 'nothing', 'thereupon', 
    'may', 'why', 'â€™s', 'therefore', 'you', 'with', 'towards', 'make', 'really', 'few', 'former', 
    'during', 'mine', 'do', 'would', 'of', 'off', 'six', 'yourself', 'becoming', 'through', 
    'seeming', 'hence', 'us', 'anywhere....}
```

This is what I attempted to do: A function to remove the stop words

```
def stop_words_remover(df):
    stop_words = list(stop_words_dict.values())
    df["Without Stop Words"] = df["Tweets"].str.lower().str.split()
    df["Without Stop Words"] = df["Without Stop Words"].apply(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in stop_words])
    return df
```

So if this was my input:

```
 [@bongadlulane, please, send, an, email, to,]
```

This is the expected output:

```
[@bongadlulane, send, email, mediadesk@eskom.c]
```

but I keep returning the former instead of the latter

Any insight would be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
stop_words = list(stop_words_dict.values())
```

This returns a list of the list of stop words

Replace it by:

```
stop_words = stop_words_dict['stopwords']
```